# Having high losses for the image processing using Pytorch - CNN

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

my image processing code is able to run, but the losses seems to be quite high - ard 21%.

The image input size suppose to be 600x600 but I resized to 256x256 due to my computer capacity. I also changed my images from RGB to Greyscale during epochs training.

The code that I am showing is just certain part of it as it is a little bit too long

```
lr = 1e-3  
batch_size = 1
num_epochs = 1
inputs=[np.array(Image.fromarray(a).resize((256,256))) for a in inputs]
labels=[np.array(Image.fromarray(a).resize((256,256))) for a in labels]
inputs_tensor = torch.Tensor(inputs).cuda()    # convert to tensor
labels_tensor = torch.Tensor(labels).cuda()
print(inputs_tensor.shape)

...

...
import sys
import numpy as np
# Testing loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    total_loss = 0

    model.eval()
    
    total_test_loss = 0

    correct_predictions = 0
    total_samples = 0
    total_samples_predict = 0

    # Store the input, ground truth, and predicted images for visualization
    input_images = []
    ground_truth_images = []
    predicted_images = []

    for delayed_tec_batch, label_batch in test_loader:
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(delayed_tec_batch)
            test_loss = criterion(output, label_batch)  # Flatten label
            total_test_loss += test_loss.item()
            
            output = output.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
            label_batch = label_batch.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
            
            #print ("output Shape ", output.shape) #predicted values
            #print ("label batch Shape ", label_batch.shape) #ground truth
            
            # Check if output is a numpy array, if not, convert it
            if isinstance(output, torch.Tensor) and output.is_cuda:
                output = output.cpu()
            output = np.array(output)
            
            
            if isinstance(label_batch, torch.Tensor) and label_batch.is_cuda:
                label_batch = label_batch.cpu()
            label_batch = np.array(label_batch)

                
            output_gray = cv2.cvtColor(output[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            (_, output_gray2) = cv2.threshold(output_gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            
            label_batch_gray = cv2.cvtColor(label_batch[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            (_, label_batch_gray2) = cv2.threshold(label_batch_gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
            
            correct_predictions += np.sum((output_gray2 == label_batch_gray2 ))
            total_samples += np.sum(label_batch_gray2 == 255)


    average_test_loss = total_test_loss / len(test_loader)
    accuracy = correct_predictions / total_samples

    print(f"Testing Loss: {average_test_loss:.4f}")
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:7f}%")
    
    print ("correct_predictions ", correct_predictions)
    print ("total_samples  ", total_samples)
    print ("total_samples_predict  ", total_samples_predict)
    print ("output ", output_gray2)
    print ("label batch ", label_batch_gray2)
    
    
    # Convert tensors to numpy arrays for visualization
    input_images.extend(delayed_tec_batch)#.cpu().numpy())
    ground_truth_images.extend(label_batch)#.cpu().numpy())
    predicted_images.extend(output)#.cpu().numpy())
 
    # Plot the learning curve
    plt.plot(total_test_loss , label='Training Loss')
    plt.plot(validation_losses, label='Validation Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Learning Curve')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([1, 64, 4, 4])
**Testing Loss: 21.7260**
**Accuracy: 5.137234%**
**correct_predictions  4456910**
**total_samples   867570**
total_samples_predict   0
output  [[255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]
 [255.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [255.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 ...
 [255.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [255.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]]
label batch  [[255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]
 [255.   0. 255. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 ...
 [255.   0.   0. ...   0.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. ... 255. 255. 255.]]


[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSc8n.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSc8n.png)
```

The losses seems to be quite high, I tried to train 10 epochs, the percentage did not drop. Does anyone can advice? or is my code wrong?

Thank You in advanced:)

Comment: The [tag:image-processing] tag has more than 42 thousand questions from people that needed help with image processing. Your title therefore is totally uninformative. Please [edit] it to be more useful. [ask] has some guidance on how to write a title.

Comment: @Waltty Could you describe the model architecture you are using, or include the code? As a starting point, try just using a very small sample from the training set - your model should be able to overfit it easily and score highly on the small sample. If that doesn't happen, it means the model isn't able to learn anything, so something would be wrong with the model and needs debugging.